# Where is the Belt(?) of Shared Space?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, magic-items, product-identification

I would swear that I've seen an item which allows anyone who has a linked copy to access the same extradimensional space; I'm 99% sure it was published by WotC or Paizo, and I'm 90% sure it was a belt. Similar to a Belt of Pockets or a Handy Haversack, the item connects to an extradimensional space and has the whole "items don't weigh anything or take up space" thing, but all of the attuned copies were connected to the *same* extradimensional space.

Basically, it lets the players hand-wave who happens to be carrying the healing potions we found back in the previous dungeon.

I want to peg the price at 10-15k per user: high for the amount of space, but with the added convenience of "yes, I *do* have that potion of Cure Serious".

I've looked in the Magic Item Compendium and the PFSRD, but have come up empty. I'm also striking out on Google.

Assuming I'm not crazy, where does this item live?

Comment: Are other details forthcoming? That is, can you remember *how* it worked? (For example, I'm imagining attuning the *belt* to the extradimensional-space-having object somehow and then the *belt* having an attached pouch to access this space.) Approximate cost? Maybe an illustration nearby? (For example, a line art illo could mean a *Third Edition* splatbook.)

Comment: Dnd4e seems to have "Pouches of Shared Acquisition" [here](http://community.wizards.com/comment/48114566#comment-48114566), although someone earlier in the thread claims he remembers these items from 3.5 as well, but no one seems able to find them.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the Pouches of Shared Acquisition is (are?) what I was thinking of. ... shouldn't be too hard to back-port them to 3.5, though, right? :)

Comment: Their like certainly seems a popular home-brew item. While hunting for something official like this I found some quite popular forum and Tumblr posts about similar things. (Which suggests it didn't exist otherwise when those posts were made)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More broadly than Pathfinder; there is the Pouches of Shared Acquisition in 4ed and [Leomund's Secret Chest Ritual](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Leomund's_Secret_Chest) has a similar effect.

I'm failing at finding a link for the Pouches; https://the-expendables.obsidianportal.com/items/pouches-of-shared-acquisition is the best I've managed so far.

Specifically to Pathfinder, while it's not exactly what you are after, putting [Ring Gates](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/ring-gates) inside a pair of bags could work. Although sadly putting them inside bags of holding may not work as they are in different non-dimensional spaces and a GM could justifiably rule that the rings aren't within 100 miles of each other.

Comment: This is the second time Ring Gates have been mentioned. (The first has been deleted.) Since this is an identification question and not asking how else it could be done, it's odd to start off an answer with a "how else it could be done" solution.

Comment: Apologies. Still it may be wrong, but that doesn't necessarily make this answer 'not useful', which is arguably what down voting is for. Even if only for preventing more Ring Gate answers.

Comment: It could be improved by putting the answer material first and leaving the Ring Gates as a secondary mention, though.

Comment: I've made the alteration, as suggested. Will also try and find a better link for the pouches.